# Truncating table values using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator, python-parser, vb

I currently have this table with the "ACT_DATE" field displaying a long string of numbers and characters.  I only need the first 4 digits, for the year, and everything else I am attempting to discard.  Is there anyway of doing this in Model Builder, or am i stuck having to clean up the table first in Excel?  I have been attempting to work with Calculate Field and Calculate Value, but I just can't seem to get anything to work out my way.

[image: Install Date]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your date format is as you specified and delimited by dash, you can do this via field calculator. Create a new text field with sufficient length, which can contain the phrase that you want to show if there is no date ("unknown install date" which has 20 characters i think) and use the PYTHON statement below

```
!ACT_DATE!.split ("-")[0] if !ACT_DATE! else "unknown install date"
```

I think it is pretty straightforward process to include this step into your model as well.

Comment: I think it's a dash, rather than an underscore, but your answer is fine nonetheless

Comment: Thanks @HDunn, were trying to write the answer on a small screen on the public transport... Now it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative but very similar approach using VB Script is this field calculate:

```vb
Left([ACT_DATE],4)
```

This returns the first 4 characters of your string, in your case the year. For rows where there is no date then nothing is returned as shown below:

[image: Example]

If you are going to do some sort of analysis then it may be prudent to convert the *text* year into an actual integer so you can query it properly. Using VB script and calculating the year into a new field the code block would be:

```vb
dim str
dim yr
str = Left( [ACT_DATE],4 )
if str = "" then
  yr = -9999 ' Return a default "no data" value
else
  yr = CLng(str) ' Convert string into a Long
end if
```